# Intersection of the probability of independent events

Tags: probability

Okay I have been solving this programming question , and in which i want to find the intersection of independent events . There are n events of 4 types .

$$p=\prod_{k=1}^n A(k)$$ $$q=\prod_{k=1}^n B(k)$$$$r=\prod_{k=1}^n C(k)$$$$s=\prod_{k=1}^n D(k)$$

where,

lets say $p$ is the probability that all events of $A$ type have occured and so on

$A(k)$ is the probability of kth event happening of $A$ type

$B(k)$ is the probability of kth event happening of $B$ type

$C(k)$ is the probability of kth event happening of $C$ type

$D(k)$ is the probability of kth event happening of $D$ type

$A(k)+B(k)+C(k)+D(k)=1$

$$1<n<1000$$

where $p$ is the probability that all events of $A$ type happening  simultaneously . Now , due to computer limits , I am loosing precision .

And I need to find out , provided that n events of 1 type have occured , what is the probability that , it is of p type . i.e $P(p|P(p\cup q\cup r \cup s))$

Basically I need to find out $p/(p+q+r+s)$

Ya I know , Its a maths forum . So I am here to explore , other methods in maths , which can be used to find this . Using unions , would be too hectic and can also lead to same problem . So what are some other methods to ,to calculate this .

Comment: If there are no patterns among the factors $A(k),B(k)\cdots$  etc. then I don't believe in the existence of alternative way to calculate $\frac{p}{p+q+r+s}$  . Your notation of a conditional probability is wrong: $p,q,r,s$  are no events, but are numbers. Probabilities actually.

Comment: okay .. Sorry forgot to mention $A(k)+B(k)+C(k)+D(k)=1$ .. i Will edit it

Comment: I allready suspected that pattern, but am afraid that it is not going to help much. Good luck.

Comment: @drhab , Okay .. :(

Comment: Calculating $\ln p = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \ln A(k)$, $\ln q = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \ln B(k)$ and so on might decrease the precision loss.